# REST endpoint to set top navigation to inherit

Tags: navigation, sharepoint-rest-api

In SharePoint Online does we have the option to use the REST API to set top navigation to inherit from the parent site?

I know it can be done manually. I also know it can be done by setting `web.Navigation.UseShared = true;` however I need to be able to invoke the change from a 2013 workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585044/set-web-properties-of-a-site-using-sharepoint-rest-api), I would try adapting that code to see if `Navigation.UseShared` is in there somewhere, e.g.:

```
Endpoint Url:  [web url]/api/web
Method: POST 
Headers:
    "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE"
    "If-Match":"*"
Data: {
    "Navigation":{
        "UseShared": true
    },
    "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Web"}
}
```

I don't know if this will work, but some experimentation might get you there.

Answer (score 0):

I reverse engineered the old JSOM and captured the request it sends to SharePoint. You need to create a post to the site in question and set a few headers.

Set the Uri to: `_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`

The headers are:

`content-type`:`text/xml`

`x-requested-with`:`XMLHttpRequest`

And the body looks like this:

`<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library"><Actions><ObjectPath Id="1" ObjectPathId="0" /><ObjectPath Id="3" ObjectPathId="2" /><ObjectPath Id="5" ObjectPathId="4" /><SetProperty Id="6" ObjectPathId="4" Name="UseShared"><Parameter Type="Boolean">true</Parameter></SetProperty></Actions><ObjectPaths><StaticProperty Id="0" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" /><Property Id="2" ParentId="0" Name="Web" /><Property Id="4" ParentId="2" Name="Navigation" /></ObjectPaths></Request>`

[image: Screenshot from Flow/PowerAutomate]